# WiFi Direct Create Group null pointer

Tags: wifi

I want to create a group to make the current device tablet as the access point, however in the callback method `onGroupInfoAvailable()` I got a null pointer of group. Why?

```
manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null); 

manager.createGroup(channel, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        manager.requestGroupInfo(channel, new GroupInfoListener() {
             public void onGroupInfoAvailable(WifiP2pGroup group) {
            if(group != null)
               Toast.makeText(SasetBladderPadActivity.this, "Group Passphrase: " 
                                   + group.getPassphrase(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
               Toast.makeText(SasetBladderPadActivity.this, "Group is null ", 
                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
public void onFailure(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(SasetBladderPadActivity.this, "Create group failed: " + arg0, \
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this too, the `WifiP2pGroup` is null in the callback... I fixed it though by waiting a bit before calling `requestGroupInfo`, not immediately from `onSuccess`...

Comment: He's right. Set a timer, or an event to enforce this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement the grouplistener and then @override the ongroupinfoavailable method. On success is just the asyn call. Actual callback needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the group is created but not shown. I will suggest to do it with the trick of implementing countdowntimer(or you may use any other timer) to start the requestGroupInfo() after a second. The modified code will be:

```
 manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
 channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null); 

 manager.createGroup(channel, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
            new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
            public void onFinish() {
                manager.requestGroupInfo(channel, new GroupInfoListener() {
                    public void onGroupInfoAvailable(WifiP2pGroup group) {
                    if(group != null)
                    Toast.makeText(SasetBladderPadActivity.this, "Group Passphrase: "
                    + group.getPassphrase(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                    Toast.makeText(SasetBladderPadActivity.this, "Group is null ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int arg0) {
    ...
```